# Command line using the mobi file?

Tags: ebook-readers, ebook-management

How to extract the.mobi file using the CMD command line? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Install Python, download [KindleUnpack](https://github.com/kevinhendricks/KindleUnpack) and unpack the mobi book using the following command:

```
python kindle_unpack.py INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FOLDER
```

(KindleUnpack only works with DRM-free books.)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems some structure wrong so that is there any way?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Did you get a KindleUnpack syntax error message or did KindleUnpack itself fail with an error message? 

Either way, you'll have to post the error message. 

If you have problems with the command line tool, there's also a [Calibre KindleUnpack plugin](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=171529), which obviously requires [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download).